# Встраивание стороннего приложения в python GUI

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, gtk3, xfce

Необходимо в свой GUI встроить одним из виджетов окно xfce4 (не все настройки, а только некоторые, например xfce4-display-settings).
Подскажите, какие есть рабочие способы это сделать на python-3.x ?

Пробовал в PyQt5 использовать createWindowContainer (window_id отлавливал через xwininfo), но оно не помещалось внутрь виджета, а открывалось поверх формы.

Опыты с gtk.Plug и gtk.Socket тоже не дали результата.

---

Обновил вопрос

Почти получилось на PyQt4:

```py
import sys
import threading
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from PyQt4 import QtCore


class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Настройки')
        #self.resize(800, 480)
        self.setMinimumWidth(800)
        self.setMinimumHeight(480)

        self.VBox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        HBox = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)

        self.Embed = QtGui.QWidget()

        Bt_Display = QtGui.QPushButton('Дисплей', self)
        Bt_Display.clicked.connect(lambda: Thread(self.Embed, "xfce4-display-settings"))
        Bt_Display.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image/system-config-display.png'))
        Bt_Display.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        HBox.addWidget(Bt_Display)

        Bt_Session = QtGui.QPushButton('Сессия', self)
        Bt_Session.clicked.connect(lambda: Thread(self.Embed, "xfce4-session-settings"))
        Bt_Session.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image/setting.png'))
        Bt_Session.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        HBox.addWidget(Bt_Session)

        Bt_Keyboard = QtGui.QPushButton('Клавиатура', self)
        # Bt_Keyboard.clicked.connect(self.DisplaySettings)
        Bt_Keyboard.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image/keyboard.png'))
        Bt_Keyboard.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        HBox.addWidget(Bt_Keyboard)

        Bt_Clock = QtGui.QPushButton('Дата и время', self)
        # Bt_Clock.clicked.connect(self.DisplaySettings)
        Bt_Clock.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon('image/clock.png'))
        Bt_Clock.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(24, 24))
        HBox.addWidget(Bt_Clock)

        self.VBox.addLayout(HBox)
        self.VBox.addWidget(self.Embed)

        Bt = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        Bt.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.VBox.addWidget(Bt)

        self.show()

def Thread(obj, command):
    t = threading.Thread(target=Run(obj, command))
    t.start()

def Run(obj, command):
    container = QtGui.QX11EmbedContainer(obj)
    container.resize(753, 366)
    container.show()
    QtCore.QObject.connect(container,
                           QtCore.SIGNAL("clientClosed()"),
                           QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

    winId = container.winId()
    process = QtCore.QProcess(container)
    options = ["--socket-id=" + str(winId)]
    process.start(command, options)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Результат:
[image]
[image]

Но появились другие проблемы:

При каждом нажатии на кнопку создается отдельный процесс:
[image]

И при нажатии на встроенные формы перестает реагировать на мышь (курсор двигается, но на нажатия клавиш не реагирует весь экран, не только GUI). Через Tab можно переключаться по кнопкам встроенной формы и так же вернуться на основное окно. После закрытия GUI мышь снова нормально работает.

Есть идеи, как это победить?
Или реализовать на других библиотеках (GTK 3.0, PyQt5)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение с использованием GTK+ 3.0

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
from subprocess import Popen

class MainWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Настройки")
        self.set_border_width(10)
        self.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
        self.set_default_size(800, 480)

        self.vbox = Gtk.Box(spacing=10, orientation='vertical')
        self.add(self.vbox)

        self.hbox1 = Gtk.Box(spacing=10, orientation='horizontal')
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox1, False, False, 0)

        self.i_display = Gtk.Image()
        self.i_display.set_from_file('image/display.png')
        self.i_display.show()
        self.b_display = Gtk.Button()
        self.b_display.add(self.i_display)
        self.b_display.show()
        self.hbox1.pack_start(self.b_display, True, True, 0)

        self.i_sesson = Gtk.Image()
        self.i_sesson.set_from_file('image/setting.png')
        self.i_sesson.show()
        self.b_sesson = Gtk.Button()
        self.b_sesson.add(self.i_sesson)
        self.b_sesson.show()
        self.hbox1.pack_start(self.b_sesson, True, True, 0)

        widget = Gtk.Frame()

        self.vbox.pack_start(widget, True, True, 0)
        widget.hide()
        self.b_display.connect("clicked", lambda x: self.Display_settings(widget))
        self.b_sesson.connect("clicked", lambda x: self.Session_settings(widget))

        self.label = Gtk.Label()
        self.label.set_text("Для настройки необходимых параметров,\nиспользуйте кнопки.")
        self.label.set_justify(Gtk.Justification.LEFT)
        self.label.show()
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.label, True, False, 0)

        self.hbox2 = Gtk.Box(spacing=10, orientation='horizontal')
        self.vbox.pack_start(self.hbox2, False, False, 0)

        self.b_back = Gtk.Button(label='Назад')
        self.b_back.set_property("width-request", 85)
        self.b_back.set_property("height-request", 15)
        self.b_back.show()
        self.b_back.connect("clicked", lambda x: self.Back(widget))
        self.hbox2.pack_start(self.b_back, True, True, 0)

        self.b_exit = Gtk.Button(label='Выход')
        self.b_exit.set_property("width-request", 85)
        self.b_exit.set_property("height-request", 15)
        self.b_exit.show()
        self.b_exit.connect("clicked", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.hbox2.pack_start(self.b_exit, True, True, 0)

        self.vbox.show()
        self.hbox1.show()
        self.hbox2.show()

    def Display_settings(self, widget):
        widget.show()
        self.label.hide()
        self.hbox1.hide()
        self.socket = Gtk.Socket()
        widget.add(self.socket)
        self.sock_id = str(self.socket.get_id())
        self.socket.show()
        cmd = ["xfce4-display-settings", "--socket-id=" + str(self.sock_id)]
        Popen(cmd)

    def Session_settings(self, widget):
        widget.show()
        self.label.hide()
        self.hbox1.hide()
        self.socket = Gtk.Socket()
        widget.add(self.socket)
        self.sock_id = str(self.socket.get_id())
        self.socket.show()
        cmd = ["xfce4-session-settings", "--socket-id=" + str(self.sock_id)]
        Popen(cmd)

    def Back(self, widget):
        self.socket.destroy()
        widget.hide()
        self.hbox1.show()
        self.label.show()


win = MainWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 2):

я не совсем понял ваши пояснения, но отвечая на ваш прямой вопрос с использованием `PyQt5`,
это может выглядеть примерно так:

```
import sys
import subprocess
import threading
import time
import win32gui
from PyQt5.QtCore    import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QWindow, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout,
                             QGridLayout, QMainWindow, QLabel) 


class Example(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setFixedSize(230, 280)
        self.widget.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow;")
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.setPixmap(
            QPixmap('images/splash_.jpg').scaled(self.size().width()/2, self.size().height())
        )
        
        self.grid_layout = QGridLayout(self.central_widget)
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 2, 1)
        
        self.v_layout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
        self.initUI()
        self.grid_layout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1) 
 
    def initUI(self):
        t = threading.Thread(target=self.runExe)
        t.start()
 
        hwnd1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "CalcFrame", "Калькулятор")
        start = time.time()
        while hwnd1 == 0:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            hwnd1 = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, "CalcFrame", "Калькулятор")
            end = time.time()
            if end - start > 5:
                return
        window = QWindow.fromWinId(hwnd1)
        widget = self.createWindowContainer(window, self.central_widget)
        self.v_layout.addWidget(widget)
 
    @staticmethod
    def runExe():
        exePath = "C:/Windows/system32/calc.exe"
        subprocess.Popen(exePath)

 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.resize(550, 400)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почти то, что нужно, но встроить необходимо не приложение Windows, а Linux.